# How to make whatsapp perform actions on behalf of react-native application?

Tags: react-native, whatsapp, whatsapi

I am trying to integrate whatsapp in my react-native app. So far the resources that I have found only tell how to send a message or open whatsapp via Linkurl from react-native application. But I want to take a step further and perform action from whatsapp. Imagine like you trigger the notification and you select the Yes and No and that performs the respective actions I want to make similar functionality but on whatsapp. After a user perform certain activity from the react-native application I want to send notification on whatsapp and without opening the react-native application the user should be able to perform action. Is there a way I can achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

React Native/JS do not have support to 'whatsapp://' scheme.

The following Schemes Only:

- mailto; //For Mailing
- tel; //For Telephone
- sms; //For SMS
- http / https; //For Hyperlinks

You can use this method to send WhatsApp message direct to a number.

> `https://wa.me/<phone#>`